# Neo4j batch insertion with .CSV files taking huge amount of time to sort&index

Tags: csv, batch-file, neo4j

I'm trying to create a database with data collected from google n-grams. It's actually a lot of data, but after the creation of the CSV files the insertion was pretty fast. The problem is that, immediately after the insertion, the `neo4j-import` tool indexes the data, and this step its taking too much time. It's been more than an hour and it looks like it achieved 10% of progress.

```
Nodes
[*>:9.85 MB/s---------------|PROPERTIES(2)====|NODE:198.36 MB--|LABE|v:22.63 MB/s-------------] 25M
Done in 4m 54s 828ms
Prepare node index
[*SORT:295.94 MB-------------------------------------------------------------------------------] 26M
```

This is the console info atm. Does anyone have a suggestion about what to do to speed up this process?

Thank you. (:

Answer (score 1):

Indexing takes a long time depending on number of nodes. I tried indexing with 10 million nodes and it took around 35 minutes, but you can still try these settings : 
Increase your page cache size which is stored in '/var/lib/neo4j/conf/neo4j.properties' file (in my ubuntu system).
 Edit the following line

```
dbms.pagecache.memory=4g
```

according to your RAM, allocate size, here, 4g means 4gb space. Also, you can try changing java memory size which is stored in neo4j-wrapper.conf

```
wrapper.java.initmemory=1024
wrapper.java.maxmemory=1024
```

You can also read neo4j documentation on this - http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-io-examples.html